# Getting India map on QGIS canvas using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7

Can I get India map extent in one click from OSM tile on canvas using PyQgis?

This is my code snippet.

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png&crs=EPSG3857'
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'MapMyIndia', 'wms')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
rect = QgsRectangle(7589389.42, 889589.56, 10842803.55, 4231219.37)
canvas.setExtent(rect)
canvas.update()
```

Comment: where are you stuck with the code snippet?

Comment: sir i need to plot india map on a single button click , so this code is written in a function which get triggered on click of that button.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following example which puts your code in a function and then a button is created on a toolbar which is connected to the function. You can test this using the Python Console:

```
def loadMap():
    if not 'MapMyIndia' in [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]:
        urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png&crs=EPSG3857'
        rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'MapMyIndia', 'wms')
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
    rlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('MapMyIndia')[0]
    canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
    rect = QgsRectangle(7589389.42, 889589.56, 10842803.55, 4231219.37)
    canvas.setExtent(rect)
    canvas.update()
    rlayer.triggerRepaint()

action = QAction(QIcon(""), "Load India", iface.mainWindow())
iface.addToolBarIcon(action)
action.triggered.connect(loadMap)
# Or to connect to a button on your plugin
#self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.loadMap)
```

Comment: actually sir i need my map on canvas when i click my plugin button

Comment: Include `self` when you insert this function into your plugin script (i.e. `def loadMap(self):`). Then instead of using `action = QAction...`, connect it to your button using something like: `self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.loadMap)`

Comment: Sir i had done this but unable to plot in one click i need to click that two time and two layer get added and second time it appears on canvas.

Comment: Did you use PluginBuilder? If so, where did you put the line `self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.loadMap)`? If it's under the `def run()` function then that would explain why you would need to click two times. Instead you should put it in the `initGui()` function so that the button is connected when the plugin is loaded.

Comment: i don't know but one first click it shows whole world map osm tile and on second click it shows the given extent.

Comment: if u can use it once in qgis and send me the code i would be helpful.

Comment: @abhinavgaurav - Edited code so that only one layer should be added. Clicking on it again will just reset the extents of the canvas.

Comment: sir still Qgis unable to load the extent of india at one click.

Comment: @abhinavgaurav - I cannot replicate your problem. Perhaps it is an issue with sending and requesting the data too quickly? You could try inserting a pause between loading the wms layer and setting the extent. Add `from time import sleep` at the beginning of the script and then directly before the line `canvas.setExtent(rect)`, add `sleep(2)`. This will create a pause of 2 seconds between loading the wms layer and setting the extent.

Comment: sir basically my problem is that on my first click it opens whole world map and on my second click on button it opens the given extent and this solution is also not correct as per my question because in this solution also i get whole world map on first click and second click shows the given extent after given time.

Comment: @abhinavgaurav - Unfortunately I cannot help you further. I tested the above code on QGIS 3.8. If you do not have this then I would suggest you download the latest version of QGIS and test the code.

Comment: actually i need this in qgis 2.18.15 version if you can resolve version issue

Comment: And one more thing in qgis 3.8 also i need to add any empty layer then only i can see the given extent i will send you code snippet

Comment: result = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:3857", "result", "memory")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result)
self.dlg.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.loadMap)

Comment: this thing is inside run then i am able to open on one click.

Comment: Unfortunately but this code is not working in QGIS 3.8 also. And sir i think you are close to give me correct answer as if one layer is added already then it plots given extent in one click.

Comment: if any one can answer this question?